# Trying to upload to S3 bucket. After 5-10 uploads it hangs

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've created a promise that uses the `aws-sdk` to upload to my S3 bucket. My application is a simple command line script to add images to S3 and update the database. I have anywhere between 300-1000 images to upload every run.

The problem I am having is it uploads 5-10 images but then seems to hang. I've confirmed this by placing a `console.log(data)` after the error checking in the promise below.

The first 5 images upload quickly, the sixth takes about a minute, the seventh a lot longer and at which point it just hangs.

**s3-upload-promise.js**

```
'use strict'

let AWS = require('aws-sdk')
let s3 = new AWS.S3()

module.exports = function(params) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
        if(err) return reject(Error(err))
        resolve(data)
      })
  })
}
```

And here is the code that calls the promise:

```
let s3UploadPromise = require('../src/s3-upload-promise/s3-upload-promise')

// Get all PNG files from given path and upload to bucket
listpng(process.argv[2]).then(function(files) {

  let promises = []

  files.forEach(function(el, i) {
    promises.push(el, s3UploadPromise({
        Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET,
        Key: 'templates/' + randomstring.generate() + '.png',
        Body: fs.createReadStream(process.argv[2] + el),
        ACL: 'public-read'
    }))
  });

  Promise.all(promises).then(function(values) {
    return console.log(values)
  })
})
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Does this have anything to do with me not closing `createReadStream`?

**Edit**

I've tried closing the stream within the the `s3.upload` callback. It didn't make any difference and it still hung:

```
s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
    params.Body.close()
    if(err) return reject(Error(err))
    resolve(data)
})
```

**Edit 2**

I added some error checking and I am getting the following error:

```
{
  message: 'Your socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections w
ill be closed.',
  code: 'RequestTimeout',
  region: null,
  time: 2016-06-19T13:14:39.223Z,
  requestId: 'F7E64E8F99E774F3',
  extendedRequestId: 'PW/mPy6t3w9U1uJc8xYKhUGi/KiSY+6yK6nq0RB21Ke1KqRmTWjjm3KXEp0qAEPDadypw+kiwCEP3upER1uecEP4Sl9Tk/lt',
  cfId: undefined,
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: true
}
```

A [comment](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/issues/29#issuecomment-21331018) on an issue on Github mentions:

> I've been noticing this a lot when using concurrency > 1, on several systems. Most of the time an uploaded folder will begin to get 400's due to timeouts after the first 10 or so requests.

Maybe adding a `Content-Length` somewhere will help. Will try.

**Edit 3**

I decided to try a different library called [knox](https://www.npmjs.com/package/knox). I get the same problem! This is crazy. It must surely an Amazon issue if two different libraries are facing the same problem?

**s3-upload-promise.js**

```
'use strict'

let knox = require('knox')
let process = require('process')

var client = knox.createClient({
  key: process.env.AWS_KEY,
  secret: process.env.AWS_SECRET,
  bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET,
});

module.exports = function(params) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    let headers = {
      'Content-Length': params.contentLength,
      'Content-Type': params.contentType,
      'x-amz-acl': params.permissions
    }

    client.putBuffer(params.buffer, params.key, headers, function(err, res){
      if(err) return reject(err)
      resolve(res)
    });
  })
}
```

Calling code ...

```
// Get all PNG files from given path
listpng(process.argv[2]).then(function(files) {

  let promises = []

  files.forEach(function(el, i) {
    let file = process.argv[2] + el;

    fs.readFile(file, function(err, data) {
      if(err) return console.log(err)

      fs.stat(process.argv[2] + el, function(err, stats) {
        if(err) return console.log(err)

        let key = process.env.S3_TEMPLATES + '/'
        let buffer = fs.createReadStream(process.argv[2] + el)

        let params = {
          buffer: data,
          key: key + randomstring.generate() + '.png',
          contentLength: stats.size,
          contentType: 'image/png',
          permissions: 'public-read',
        }

        promises.push(s3Uploader(params))

        Promise.all(promises).then(function(values) {
          return console.log(values)
        })
      })
    })
  })
})
```

Not sure what else to do now.

Comment: Hey! did you find any solution to it?